# How can I extract 20% descending loss in this code?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I have the following code:

```
def model_fn():
keras_model = create_keras_model()
 return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec=federated_train_data[0].element_spec,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
```

In this code, I want to average by sorting 20% of the items corresponding to the loss in descending order.

```
 #server select in the top20% clients
selected_clients_weights = clinet_select(client_weights)
```

How can I extract loss for sorting clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting point would be to look at the directory [`tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg) and see how Federated Averaging is implemented.

To extend this to average only the top 20% based on loss will require two things:

1. Add an additional output from the [`client_update`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/b13046fa47b2eab4f38c37fc41d7fba64f192bb1/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L192) function, in this case a `loss` value.
2. Replace the [`tff.federated_mean`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/b13046fa47b2eab4f38c37fc41d7fba64f192bb1/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L131) aggregation with a call to [`tff.federated_collect`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_collect). This will return a sequence. This could then be sorted (possibly by weight) and averaged inside a new `tff.tf_computation` decorated method that is applied to the result of `tff.federated_collect` with [`tff.federated_map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_map).

Comment: Do I change simple_fedavg_tf.py and simple_fedavg_tff.py  in this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg) ?? I followed the installation guide and installed it, but I couldn't test it by running the files here. can you tell me more detail How to test and design the algorithm I asked. I would be very grateful if you could explain in detail.

Comment: Yes, that is the location of simple_fed_avg and both the tf.py and tff.py files will need to be changed. The [README](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/README.md#instructions) has pretty good instructions.

Comment: In this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L192), I extract `losses = output.loss` and collect them via  `collect_loss = tff.federated_collect(client_outputs.losses)` at  [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L192). Is it correct to do this?

Comment: Please let me know how to sort`collect_loss` and How do I know the `weight_delta`  of the clients in this list??

Comment: The code might be easier to work with if the entire output structure is collected, `tff.federated_collect(client_output)`. This way the `loss` is paired with the `weight_delta`.

Comment: How can I access to value in sequence??

Comment: In TFF, applying a function to a sequence is done using [`tff.sequence_reduce`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/sequence_reduce) or `tff.sequence_map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/sequence_map).  The [Custom Federated Algorithms, Part 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_2) has example usages.

Comment: Is there any way to find out the `weight_delta` and `loss_sum` of each client?? I want to  select clients based on the `loss_sum` generated for each client and do `tff.federated_mean` using `weight_delta` of the selected clients.

Comment: Is there any way to find the mean of the `weight_delta` for only some of the clients??